# Python3 numpy array addition

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np

pp = np.array(p)       # p is some array

print(pp[0])
print(pp[1])
print(pp[0] + pp[1])

results in : [138 138 138]
         [138 138 148]
         [20 20 40]
```

Why does this happen? Why is the addition wrong?

Comment: What exactly is p?

Comment: What is `print(pp)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your array is evidently composed of unsigned bytes (dtype=uint8).  Your values are wrapping around within the 0..255 range of this data type.